# What are the consequences of Trump's election for Muslims visiting the US?

Tags: usa, event-based-effects, islam

Donald Trump [has been known](http://time.com/4139476/donald-trump-shutdown-muslim-immigration/) to call for some extreme policies if he's elected president:

> Republican presidential frontrunner Donald Trump called Monday for “a total and complete shutdown of Muslims entering the United States until our country’s representatives can figure out what is going on.”

Should Muslim tourists visiting the US next year be worried about the consequences of the election? Many people plan their travels more than 6 months in advance and therefore this question is not just of theoretical value.

Comment: He will not be in office for 2 more months, there is plenty of time to visit the country :)

Comment: @Vince plenty of people have already bought tickets for the summer, well after Trump takes office

Comment: Speculative and opinion based at present. He's not even president yet. Closing.

Comment: Apparently the new President promised to expand Trump resort Cuba for special categories of tourist. The [reviews on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Guantanamo+Bay+Detention+Facilities/@19.9021284,-75.1052806,2834m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m7!3m6!1s0x0:0xea5ddb2a3e52e6b1!8m2!3d19.9026677!4d-75.1001787!9m1!1b1) are all very positive.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open as we have a bit more information now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to predict that at this point. Trump has been extremely vague on how this would be implemented in practice. He won't even be in in office for another two months. We don't even know if he'll actually implement it. For all we know, it could have just been a populist attention grabber for the election.

When he is actually sworn in and/or starts making concrete statements and/or policies regarding this, it will be possible to answer this more objectively. At this point, we can do nothing but speculate.