# Fidel Castro's death - possible outcomes for tourists?

Tags: event-based-effects, cuba

We are about to leave for Cuba today for 9 days. [9 national mourning days has been declared](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/11/26/americas/fidel-castro-blog/index.html) due to Fidel's recent death.

How is this going to a affect a common tourist in Cuba nowadays, in terms of transportation and maybe local attractions?

Comment: vtc as opinion based. We can't predict the future.

Comment: It literally just happened.  I get the concern, but aside from the interest aspect of being in Cuba at a vey important time in their history, any impact on your holiday at present is complete speculation, and as such I'm closing as opinion based.

Comment: @MarkMayo That makes no sense as a reason to close: even if we don't know *now*, we'll surely have a pretty good idea within 24 hours?

Comment: @jpatokal I see your point, but isn't that like asking the day before the US election what will happen afterwards? It's solely opinion at the moment. If it becomes answerable, then sure, it's askable,  but currently under the [help], we can't technically answer it :/

Comment: Fidel wasn't ruling the country for 8 years now. Why would his death affect anything?

Comment: @JonathanReez museums may be closed, banks may be closed, etc

Comment: It would be interesting to see if the "9 days of national mourning" are anything like the Thai's. When the Thai king passed, we had a useful on-topic question for how that might affect tourists. I think the wording of this one just needs to be cleaned up a little to match the Thai one and it would be a useful and on topic question.

Comment: @MarkMayo We had a bunch of questions about how Trump being elected would affect visitors to the US (particularly Muslim ones), and they were not closed...

Comment: I don't understand the drive to close this question. It's a perfectly reasonable thing to want to know if you're about to go to Cuba right now. If someone has the knowledge to answer it as more details about the situation emerge, then they can do so. If not, it will stay unanswered until it eventually is closed for being obsolete.

Comment: @JonathanReez You should write that as an answer. A man that has been retired for 9 years of public life has died, and that's it. Government affairs won't change because the government has changed. Adored or hated, nobody considered him a religious figure (as the Thai king was considered) but just a man. It probably won't be wise to do jokes about his death if you are in Cuba, but I doubt that there is a moment when it is wise to do jokes about any Castro in Cuba. So, business as usual.

Comment: @jpatokal yes it was? http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82213/what-are-the-consequences-of-trumps-election-for-muslims-visiting-the-us

Answer (score 5):

As for the nine days of mourning:

> during the national mourning public activities and shows will be halted, the national flag will be flown at half-mast in public buildings and military establishments and radio and television will broadcast informational, patriotic and historical programming

As per ["Viva Fidel!", Cubans begin mass mourning for Castro](http://news.trust.org/item/20161126202712-j4nlo/?source=hpbreaking):

> Streets were quiet following the news, and some normally busy restaurants were all but empty, but Castro's death did not bring daily life in Havana to a complete halt. Some Cubans went to buy vegetables in markets and chicken in state-run stores.
>
> "Usually we're full, but today only tourists have come and maybe a few Cubans. Usually it's the other way around. It seems Cubans feel funny about enjoying themselves so soon after Fidel died," said Raul Tamayo, a doorman at La Roca, a popular restaurant in Havana's central Vedado district.

Finally you should note the country is ruled by Raúl Castro for more than eight years now. You could add another two when he was in "acting" capability before that. Everything I read says his rule is very stable. So if you are afraid of unrest, that is very unlikely.

Comment: That depends on the definition of attraction: if it's state run it's closed, if it's private it's empty. That's why I included both quotes...? Transportation runs, that's why I included "did not bring daily life in Havana to a complete halt".

Comment: Great answer, I would add maybe that cultural life will probably be at pause during these 9 days,  probably even at remote resorts mostly frequented by tourist, and this is one of the main attractions for people that visit the country. Musicians playing at restaurants and the like will be absent, concerts and similar presentations will be cancelled, etc. If you were planning to visit just to relax on a beach you will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

This [CTV News article](http://www.ctvnews.ca/world/tourists-experience-havana-without-live-music-museums-or-beer-1.3179281) says it's not a normal tourist experience:

> They came for salsa music and mojitos and ended up wandering through a city turned still and silent by nine days of national mourning for Fidel Castro.
>
> As Cuba prepares a massive commemoration for the leader of its socialist revolution, tens of thousands of high-season travellers have found themselves accidental witnesses to history -- and smack in the middle of a sombre city that's little like its usual exuberant self.

...

> Many museums have closed their doors, and a state-sanctioned ban on live music has shuttered concerts and nightspots including the famed Tropicana nightclub. Old Havana these days is eerily devoid of the roving troubadours whose Buena Vista Social Club croonings normally echo through the cobblestone streets. And the 1950s classic cars that function as collective taxis are doing without the usual reggaeton at max volume.

I suppose these will be the conditions throughout the 9 days.